# Sharepoint 2013 SP1 Personal Blog date and title truncated with title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, blog, mysite

[image]

This personal blog at mysite. For this issues i cannot add customs css right?
what i think right now, i want change date formatting become "09 Nov" not "09 November", is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Posts list of your blog -> list settings -> click on "Created" column, there you schould be able to change the showing date format to "Standard"

Comment: it still not working.. it still show 09 November not 09 Nov :(
By the way this blog at My Site, that means personal blog. how can i make formatted date 09 Nov by default?

Answer (score 1):

Since in SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering is a default rendering mode, i would recommend the following approach to set `PublishingDate` field format. 
The solution is to override the format of `PublishingDate` field before rendering the post as demonstrated below:

**JavaScript template**

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  ListTemplateType: 301,
  OnPreRender: function(ctx) { 
      var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
      for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
      {
         var monthString = rows[i]["PublishedDate.MonthDayOnly"];
         var monthParts = monthString.split(" ");
         monthParts[0] = monthParts[0].substring(0,3);
         rows[i]["PublishedDate.MonthDayOnly"] = monthParts.join(" "); 
      }
  }
});
```

**How to apply changes**

Probably the easiest way would to insert the specified code into the page using `Content Editor` or `Script Editor` web parts.

1. Open the page in Edit mode
2. Add Script Editor web part and insert the provided code by enclosing it using `script` tag
3. Save the changes

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Hello sir, right now this personal blog at My Site, i can edit page but only for my blog only, how can i want make to all other user's blog? 
BTW, at personal blog it dont have content editor.